# How to load the dataset which I have programmatically created to ReportViewer Control in vb .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, report

When I am doing my project on vb .Net, I programmatically create a dataset.  But when I try to generate a report using ReportViewer Control Class, I can't able to load the dataset which I have created programmatically.  Instead, I can get the option to create a new dataset by using wizard.  So, is there any way to load the dataset which I created programmatically in the ReportViewer Control?

### Code

```
    Dim dadapt As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select Name As [Name of the Member on Leave/Duty], AName As [Name of member assigned work], colDOL As [Date], colClass As [Class] From TabAdjustment Order By colDOL", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    dadapt.Fill(dt)
```

Is there any way to use the above specified DataTable Reference dt while creating a Report using ReportViewer Control

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ReportDataSource as a link between your dataset and the reportviewer. Basically you set the rds.name to the name of as it appears in the rdlc file at design time, and the rds.value to a data source object that matches the object you used at designtime. In other words you can use a different dataset/table etc at runtime, as long as it offers the same properties etc.
 Here's a bit of code that might help. It's in C#, but should be easy enough to translate:

```
  public void SetupReport(string reportName, string rdsName, object rdsValue, List<ReportParameter> parms)
    {

        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();

        //get the rdlc resource eg "Project.Report4.rdlc"   it has to be the full name including the default namespace  
        rv1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = reportName;

        //remove default reportdatasource
        rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

        //configure the new reportdatasource . . .
        rds.Name = rdsName;   //case sensitive even in VB eg "ds_tblXXX"
        rds.Value = rdsValue; //eg tblXXX


        //. . .and add it to the report
        rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);


        //if there's a parm block, set that
        if ((parms != null))
        {
            rv1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parms);
        }

        //and display it

        this.Show();

        //load up the report with data
        rv1.RefreshReport();
        cGeneral.ms(0);

    }
```